# OpenVPN Server subnet addresses conflict

Tags: dhcp, openvpn

Where I work we have the same subnet pool (192.168.1.x) that I have at home. Hence I can't reach to home's subnet addresses when connected to the OpenVPN Server.

What's the best/easiest way to resolve this conflict? I'd like to avoid changing my home router DHCP pool addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has the same problem on a linux computer: You can use the openvpn connection for only selected programs using network namespaces!

This little script connects to openvpn and opens a bash that uses the VPN. Everything else on your computer does not see the VPN (and so it can connect to your local network). Every program started in this shell will use the VPN connection (and cannot access the local net).

I assume that the startup command of openvpn is in the file ./start_openvpn and the stop command in ./stop_openvpn:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=`hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1`

ip netns add myvpn
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link set veth1 netns myvpn
ip netns exec myvpn ifconfig veth1 192.168.99.1/24 up
ifconfig veth0 192.168.99.2/24 up
ip netns exec myvpn route add default gw 192.168.99.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.99.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source $IP
ip netns exec myvpn ./start_openvpn &
ip netns exec myvpn sudo -u myunixuser /bin/bash

./stop_openvpn
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.99.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source $IP
ifconfig veth0 down
ip netns exec myvpn ifconfig veth1 down
ip link delete veth0
ip netns delete myvpn
```

*myunixuser* is the local Linux user you usually work with. This script has to be called as root user.

After work is done, close the shell with **exit**.

If you need a second VPN-shell just call

```
ip netns exec myvpen /bin/bash
```

*before* you exited from the first shell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the good lesson here is to never ever use 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.0.1/24 in corporate environment, just like never to use 802.1q VLAN ID 1.

But, there are cases when you can't do anything. For those cases, OpenVPN starting from 2.4 supports internal stateless address translation (NAT), a.k.a. network mapping. From `man openvpn`:

```
--client-nat snat|dnat network netmask alias
        This pushable client option sets up a stateless one-to-one NAT rule on
        packet addresses (not ports), and is useful in cases where routes or
        ifconfig settings pushed to the client would create an IP numbering
        conflict.

        network/netmask (for example 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0) defines the
        local view of a resource from the client perspective, while
        alias/netmask (for example 10.64.0.0/255.255.0.0) defines the remote
        view from the server perspective.

        Use snat (source NAT) for resources owned by the client and dnat
        (destination NAT) for remote resources.

        Set --verb 6 for debugging info showing the transformation of
        src/dest addresses in packets.
```

So, you add a line into your client .conf file:

```
client-nat dnat 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.0
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

and then if your server-side has 192.168.1.5 system, the client will be able to access it as 192.168.2.5, resolving an addressing conflict. And so on.

Comment: When using `client-nat`, you probably want to include the line `route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0` as well in your client config, in order to send the relevant packets through the VPN interface, instead of the default gateway.

Comment: @Lacek this is indeed correct, I edited an answer

Answer (score 0):

IMO that's a poor choice for an openvpn subnet, since it's used by so many home routers. Unless you can change the openvpn config however, you're going to have to change your home network. Since it's DHCP, it shouldn't cause too much trouble -- just change it to something like 192.168.42.0/24 and have your devices reconnect.

EDIT:

The "push" directive will add the network that's behind the OpenVPN server (your work's network) to the routing table on the client (your home computer). The push directive must match the work subnet and it should **not** be the same as the home subnet.

Comment: I can change my openvpn configuration, right now I have as route parameter: "push "route 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0" because the pool address of my LAN DHCP starts from 192.168.1.100